# Multi-Line text Button Xamarin.Forms

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, multiline

theres is a way to set a multi-line text to a Xamarin.Forms Button??

I've tried Button.Text = "something \n xxjjjxx" But don't work.

Answer (score 14):

A simple solution will use:

```
&#x0a;
```

Comment: Simple and worked perfectly for me...  Text="First Line &#x0a;Second Line"... Thank you

Comment: This should be at the top ^^^

Answer (score 5):

There is an excellent example on how to achieve this on Github. It is quite simple really. Just create your own control that inherits from ContentView and contains a grid.

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class MultiLineButton : ContentView
{
    public event EventHandler Clicked;

    protected Grid ContentGrid;
    protected ContentView ContentContainer;
    protected Label TextContainer;

    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (String)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
            RaiseTextChanged();
        }
    }

    public new View Content
    {
        get { return ContentContainer.Content; }
        set
        {
            if (ContentGrid.Children.Contains(value))
                return;

            ContentContainer.Content = value;
        }
    }

    public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Text",
        returnType: typeof(String),
        declaringType: typeof(MultiLineButton),
        defaultValue: null,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: TextValueChanged);

    private static void TextValueChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((MultiLineButton)bindable).TextContainer.Text = (String)newValue;
    }

    public event EventHandler TextChanged;
    private void RaiseTextChanged()
    {
        if (TextChanged != null)
            TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public MultiLineButton()
    {
        ContentGrid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
        ContentGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });

        ContentContainer = new ContentView
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };

        TextContainer = new Label
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };
        ContentContainer.Content = TextContainer;

        ContentGrid.Children.Add(ContentContainer);

        var button = new Button
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#01000000")
        };

        button.Clicked += (sender, e) => OnClicked();

        ContentGrid.Children.Add(button);

        base.Content = ContentGrid;

    }

    public void OnClicked()
    {
        if (Clicked != null)
            Clicked(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
<local:MultiLineButton x:Name="AssessmentToolDetailButton" 
    WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="Blue">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Hello" TextColor="White" Font="16"/>
        <Label Text="World" TextColor="White" Font="16"/>
    </StackLayout>
</local:MultiLineButton>
```

You can also place an image in the button by setting its content.

In my example I modified Dans original code in order to make the text bindable. Just set the Text value instead of the Content like this:

```
<local:MultiLineButton Text="{Binding Description}" />
```

All credit goes to Danvanderboom for his example:
[ConentButton by Danvanderboom](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/241)

Comment: this solution worked for me but my buttons need to have rounded corners so that they are consistent with everything else.

Comment: @fireydude You can easily style your button any way you would like. In the code above you just need to set the properties on the Button that is added to the grid. I only set the Vertical, Horizontal and BackgroundColor but you can set the Borders as well. Something like: BorderRadius = 4, BorderWidth = 2, BorderColor = Color.White,

Comment: Perfect and Clean code!. Just a small comment. Button Click was not working, I used the Tap Gesture instead

Answer (score 4):

> This is mainly a problem with iOS because Android will wrap the text
>   by default.  I tried the solution provided by Kasper and it worked
>   however the buttons do not have rounded corners and the appearance is
>   not consistent with other buttons in my app.

A simple solution is to use a custom renderer (ButtonRenderer) to set the LineBreakMode to WordWrap.  If you then set the width of the button in the Xaml you get words to appear on different lines.

**iOS**

```
public class WrappedButtonRenderer: ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(4, 4, 4, 4);
        Control.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        Control.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
    }
}
```

**Android** does not require a custom renderer because it wraps by default.

This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28621) with Xamarin Forms.

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I put this into a `StackLayout`.

Comment: @fireydude do you know how to do that for TabbedPage tab button?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've seen two lined buttons often. You have two options that I think might work:

1. Create a Custom Renderer and Extend the respective Button Class to do more on each native platform. Might be a harder
2. Create a Xamarin.Forms Class that extends a View that can contains a StackLayout and smaller elements such as multi-line labels, then you can use a `TapGestureRecognizer` to use with your view and treat it like a button.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [fireydude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43808248/747369), I created a MultilineButton control and renderer for iOS so I could add text alignment. This uses the Xamarin.Forms.TextAlignment enum.

*MultilineButton.cs*

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace APP_NAMESPACE.Controls
{
    public class MultilineButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty HorizontalTextAlignmentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "HorizontalTextAlignment",
            returnType: typeof(TextAlignment),
            declaringType: typeof(MultilineButton),
            defaultValue: TextAlignment.Start
        );

        public TextAlignment HorizontalTextAlignment
        {
            get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(HorizontalTextAlignmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HorizontalTextAlignmentProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

*MultilineButtonRenderer.cs*

```
using APP_NAMESPACE.Controls;
using APP_NAMESPACE.iOS.Renderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MultilineButton), typeof(MultilineButtonRenderer))]
namespace APP_NAMESPACE.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class MultilineButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null) { return; }

            UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment horizontalAlignment;
            UITextAlignment textAlignment;

            // We have to use ButtonRenderer, so cast the Element to MultilineButton to get the HorizontalTextAlignment property
            var button = (MultilineButton)Element;
            if (button == null) { return; }

            switch(button.HorizontalTextAlignment)
            {
                case TextAlignment.Center:
                    horizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                    textAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
                    break;
                case TextAlignment.End:
                    horizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    textAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
                    break;
                default:
                    horizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    textAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
                    break;
            }

            Control.HorizontalAlignment = horizontalAlignment;
            Control.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            Control.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = textAlignment;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it within XAML:

```
<controls:MultilineButton Text="This Button is Centered!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
```